# MetalKit - Drawable.texture assertion error

Tags: swift, macos, metal

I am new to `MetalKit` and trying to convert [this tutorial](http://mhorga.org/2016/05/02/using-metalkit-part-10.html) from `playground` back to `OSX` app:

```
    import MetalKit

public class MetalView: MTKView {

    var queue: MTLCommandQueue! = nil
    var cps: MTLComputePipelineState! = nil

    required public init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        registerShaders()
    }


    override public func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        if let drawable = currentDrawable {
            let command_buffer = queue.commandBuffer()
            let command_encoder = command_buffer.computeCommandEncoder()
            command_encoder.setComputePipelineState(cps)
            command_encoder.setTexture(drawable.texture, atIndex: 0)
            let threadGroupCount = MTLSizeMake(8, 8, 1)
            let threadGroups = MTLSizeMake(drawable.texture.width / threadGroupCount.width, drawable.texture.height / threadGroupCount.height, 1)
            command_encoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadGroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadGroupCount)
            command_encoder.endEncoding()
            command_buffer.presentDrawable(drawable)
            command_buffer.commit()
        }
    }

    func registerShaders() {
        queue = device!.newCommandQueue()
        do {
            let library = device!.newDefaultLibrary()!
            let kernel = library.newFunctionWithName("compute")!
            cps = try device!.newComputePipelineStateWithFunction(kernel)
        } catch let e {
            Swift.print("\(e)")
        }
    }
}
```

I got an error at the line:

```
command_encoder.setTexture(drawable.texture, atIndex: 0)
```

> failed assertion `frameBufferOnly texture not supported for compute.'

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to write to a drawable's texture from a compute function, you'll need to tell the `MTKView` that it should configure its layer not to be framebuffer-only:

```
metalView.framebufferOnly = false
```

With this value set to false, your drawable will give you a texture with the `shaderWrite` usage flag set, which is required when writing a texture from a shader function.

Comment: Where should we set this? within the `MetalView` Class?

Comment: OK, I got it. I set `self.frameBufferOnly = false` and it works.

Comment: This is strange, I found if I run the code in playground, I don't need to set this line, but If I adopt the code to an App, I need to add this .

Comment: I had to put `self.framebufferOnly = false` in the `init`. Setting this in the draw call is too late to avoid the assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue even I set the frameBufferOnly to `false` and print the boolean for double check before using the drawable.

But when I turn off the `GPU frame capture`, no more assertion occurs (for now at least). Still don't know why.

`Menu > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Run > Options > GPU Frame Capture`: **Disabled**